# Rails remote link_to issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I understand that `remote:true` on `link_to` is nice for actions like Create, Update, Delete.

I came across some code that uses it to navigate between views for example:

```
<%= link_to "View Message", conversation_path(conversation), remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

and on server side handle the request like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'show', :layout => false }...
```

the js view looks like this:

```
var form_str = '<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'messages' %>';
var form_footer = '<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "reply_form" %>';
$('#messages_view').html( form_str );
$('#messages_footer').html( form_footer );
```

I think it's a little smelly, but not 100% sure, is this a proper way to write links in standard rails app? doesn't turbolinks take care of not rendering entire ui again and I can just use regular links ?

Comment: As you mentioned turbolinks takes care of most of that so I'm not sure what one would gain of using this.

Comment: The proper way is just use link_to without remote and on server just write code that re render entire view right?

Comment: I believe that is correct.